# Assembly Language 2 Book on Push and Pop

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

**First question**
Which statement is true about what will happen when the example code runs?

```
1: main PROC
2: mov eax,30
3: push eax
4: push 40
5: call Ex3Sub
6: INVOKE ExitProcess,0
7: main ENDP
8:
9: Ex3Sub PROC
10: pusha
11: mov eax,80
12: popa
13: ret
14: Ex3Sub ENDP
```

a. EAX will equal 40 on line 6

b. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 6

c. EAX will equal 30 on line 6

d. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 13

**Second Question**
Which statement is true about what will happen when the example code runs?

```
1: main PROC
2: push 10
3: push 20
4: call Ex2Sub
5: pop eax
6: INVOKE ExitProcess,0
7: main ENDP
8:
9: Ex2Sub PROC
10: pop eax
11: ret
12: Ex2Sub ENDP
```

a. EAX will equal 10 on line 6

b. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 10

c. EAX will equal 20 on line 6

d. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 11

*1. By looking at this I think that EAX would still equal 30 at the end of line 6 because eax was just pushed on the stack not a change in value*

*2. This one I would believe it would equal 10 because of LIFO (last in first out). EAX would equal 10 because it was the last one in.*

This is a new concept, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the first one right. The second one is tricky, it will most probably crash on line 11 (answer `d`). That's because in `Ex2Sub` the `pop eax` removes the topmost item from the stack, which is the return address. So when `ret` tries to do the same, it will see the next item, which was `20` and unlikely to be a correct code address.