# Stack push and pop in assembly language for x86 processors

Tags: assembly, stack, masm, irvine32

I am learning assembly language for x86 processor, there are 2 questions I would like you to take a look for me if I answered it correctly.

1. Which statement is true about what will happen when the example code runs?

```
 1: main PROC
 2:      mov edx, 0
 3:      mov eax, 40
 4:      push eax
 5:      call Ex5Sub
 6:      INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
 7: main ENDP
 8: 
 9:Ex5Sub PROC 
10:      pop eax
11:      pop edx 
12:      push eax
13:      ret 
14:Ex5Sub ENDP
```

a. EDX will equal 40 on line 6
b. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 13
c. EDX will equal 0 on line 6
d. The program will halt with a runtime error on Line 11

My Answer: (d) as the there is only one element 40 pushed into stack and there is no other element to be popped.

2. Is the same as second questions posted in this link [Assembly Language 2 Book on Push and Pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630420/assembly-language-2-book-on-push-and-pop). I do not have enough reputation to put comment and ask about it. The person who answered to this question said (d) but I do not understand why it is (d) as from what I learned from book is that after pop eax is executed, the esp will be incremented and point to the previous value, so when it is ret, it should be 10.

Your patience in explaining to me would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Install Visual Studio and try it out :-)  The question is from Irvine's book. On his homepage are hints to install and use VS: http://kipirvine.com/asm/

Comment: Thank you for telling me this information and the link!

Answer (score 3):

The answer for #1 will actually help you understand #2 without having to post a comment to that other question.

Sorry, but (d) is wrong.  Your assumption that there is only one element pushed into the stack is incorrect.  The `push eax` instruction on line 4 places one element into the stack, but the `call Ex5Sub` instruction on line 5 places one more element into the stack: the return address for the subroutine.  That's what `call` instructions do: they push a return address into the stack, and then they jump to the destination.  The return address is always the address of the instruction immediately following the `call` instruction, so in this case, the return address is the address of line 6.

So, the subroutine pops the return address from the stack, pops 40 from the stack into `edx`, puts the return address back in the stack, and returns.  Therefore, `edx` will hold 40 upon returning from the subroutine, which means that (a) is correct.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Could you help me to confirm whether my understanding is correct? So at line 5, this moment stack has 40 , then pop eax = pop 40, pop edx = saving the 40 into edx? because the example in the book (for example, pop eax is a number and then using mov to copy to another variable) I have never seen pop edx(pop reg) as a direct way copy the value into edx. So I am not sure if it is like that. Please correct if i am wrong. When push eax at line 12, is put the return address back in the stack? So it is mean both eax and edx are 40 in this subroutine?

Comment: and i saw from book that when a procedure returns a value in a register should not be pushed or popped, so at line 10 means it restores eax, so pop edx is used to store the 40 when pop edx also means restore edx? I will be really appreciate if you could explain to me. Thank you very much

Comment: no, `pop eax` = `pop address-of-line-6`, then `pop edx` = `40 -> edx`. Yes, `push eax` = `push address-of-line-6`. No, `eax` and `edx` have different values

Comment: line 10 does not restore `eax`, it destroys whatever `eax` contained by popping a value from the stack, and in any case this is the beginning of the subroutine, it has nothing to do with subroutines returning values.

Comment: look: this subroutine is highly unconventional, we do not pop things from the stack like that, certainly not the return address, so mr. Irvine has chosen a highly un-pedagogical way to teach whatever he is trying to teach. And he has managed to confuse you.